# Hazelcast 3.6 - Map get element

Tags: hazelcast

I have tried to make a simple demo using hazelcast 3.6 version. Basically I started the console application , then I added an element to the cluster from a client code.

```
public class GettingStartedClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new  ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.addAddress("127.0.0.1:5704");
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
        IMap<Integer, String> map = client.getMap("customers");
        System.out.println("Map Size:" + map.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(map.get(i+1));
        }
        map.put(0, "Emre");

    }

}
```

Later, Using the command line I switch to ns customer and I execute m.get , m.values and m.keys commands. m.values and m.keys are returning the element in the map however m.get returns null.

```
hazelcast[customers] > m.keys
0
Total 1

hazelcast[customers] > m.values
Emre
Total 1

hazelcast[customers] > m.get 0
null
```

Am I missing someting ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The key used in the Demo App is not Integer but String. So in order to make it work, your client code should be like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new  ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.addAddress("127.0.0.1:5704");
    HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    IMap<String, String> map = client.getMap("customers");
    System.out.println("Map Size:" + map.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(map.get(i+1));
     }

    map.put("0", "Emre");
}
```

You can checkout the source code of the demo app from github :
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/console/ConsoleApp.java

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast console assume the key to be a string, and tries to find the key "0" which doesn't exist